# Why was my not constructive flag declined?

Tags: discussion, flagging

I left a comment on [When do you check if you lose](https://boardgames.stackexchange.com/q/28907/6692).

> This question does not show any research effort. The [first Google result](http://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Card/Details.aspx?multiverseid=376460) for "prosperity mtg" has a ruling that says "10/4/2004 If both players run out of cards during this effect, the game is a draw." – [Rainbolt](https://boardgames.stackexchange.com/users/6692/rainbolt) [Feb 14 at 21:06](https://boardgames.stackexchange.com/questions/28907/when-do-you-check-if-you-lose#comment38862_28907)

The response I got was this:

> I realize that now, but thanks for pointing out my stupidity and yours or lack there of, SENPAI – [eric](https://boardgames.stackexchange.com/users/15295/eric) [Feb 14 at 23:57](https://boardgames.stackexchange.com/questions/28907/when-do-you-check-if-you-lose#comment38864_28907)

For those who may not know, referring to someone as senpai in this way is a form of sarcastic admiration. That sarcasm, plus a jab about someone's stupidity, makes up the entirety of the comment. Comments really don't get any less constructive than this.

I flagged the comment as "Not Constructive", but the flag was declined. Was raising a flag the wrong thing to do? Did I raise the wrong type of flag (something I've been known to do in the past)?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think you were right in raising a flag on that comment, but you should have went with "rude or offensive" instead of "not constructive". I think a rude or offensive comment is worse for the site than a non-constructive comment. So if you took offense, I think it would be more appropriate to use that flag instead. Being rude is never constructive, so "rude or offensive" is actually more specific than "not constructive". I mean, assuming that you took offense.

On a side note... I don't mean to start an argument about who started it, but your own comment probably also came off as rude. I mean, [lmgtfy](http://lmgtfy.com/?q=prosperity+mtg) on a [new user](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/172970/negative-comments-drive-new-users-away-how-can-we-fix-this/173050#173050) seems [really inappropriate](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/15650/ban-lmgtfy-let-me-google-that-for-you-links).

Comment: This does not answer the question, but it might if you add an explanation as to why I should have used a different type of flag. Regarding the second paragraph, [posting links to Google along with a constructive argument is considered acceptable](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/109715/254466). The real problem with my comment is that it was not phrased in the nicest way possible - something I have taken note of and will attempt to improve.

Comment: @Rainbolt I answered your first question, "was raising a flag the right thing to do?" Yes it was. I first speculated about how the mod might have looked at the whole comment discussion instead of just the one you flagged, but since that's speculation I left that out. Would like to hear that from the mod in question.

Comment: Okay, thanks for expanding your answer to include an explanation. I wasn't offended by the comment - I flag comments like these so that future readers don't have to parse through a bunch of useless information to find what they are looking for. My comment helps readers find the answer. The other comment does not. I hope mods recognize the difference between the two comments, and react with more granularity than "Keep all the comments." or "Nuke all the comments."